# Is running allowed?

Tags: professionalism, unprofessional-behavior

I just got scolded by my instructor for running.
I was chasing after someone who asked me a question, and I found the answer after the person left the room. And on the way back I naruto-ran outdoors for 25m just because it felt good.

My instructor told me to not run, because our company has an professional image to lose, which we would certainly lose if someone saw me running crazy as that
(we don't really have an image, we are just about a small company of 30 people)

My question is if it's ok to run or if you are even caring about such small details

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/100255/discussion-on-question-by-jannis-is-running-allowed).

Answer (score 13):

> on the way back I naruto-ran outdoors

There are few businesses which would be happy to see you naruto-run. Most other companies want to show a face of adult people behaving adult.

> we don't really have an image

Every company has an image, official or not, advertised or not.

> My question is if it's ok to run...

In your free time, anything is OK. On company time, there are rules and regulations about many things. Running is a risk factor, and in the case of an accident, the company might get a lot of trouble. If nothing more, just the paperwork and the legal stuff are already enough.

> ... or if you are even caring about such small details

We do not care about you or your company . We have no idea who you are. **But we advise you warmly** to behave according to your age, in an environment where you are expected to behave as such.

And, a work-related accident is not a "such small detail" at all.

---

> My **instructor** told me to not run, because our **company** ...

and

> we make cashregister software

I assume you mean "trainer" or supervisor" or manager"...

Comment: 'What kind of a software development company ... has "instructors"? ' - one where *instruction* is provided, perhaps to more junior staff? It's not *that* strange an idea...

Comment: Any software company that's serious about training its new staff? We're a comparable company and we have some devs who are instructors to new hires as well.

Comment: Maybe that _'instructor'_ is some senior dev whos responsibility is to tutor fresh juniors?

Comment: google translator says instructor/trainer

Comment: I understand the concept, but they are most of the times called "trainers". Until now, I associated the word "instructor" with physical activities (e.g. gyms), and I never heard anyone being e.g. an "instructor for the C language".

Comment: @Jannis: google translator is not a good reference for how words should be used ;)

Comment: In germany you have official, standardized apprenticeships for software development (Ausbildung zum Fachinformatiker) -  so if it is like this, it does not sound strange at all. @Jannis are you in an apprenticeship/Ausbildung?

Comment: "Instructor" may not be the commonest term in English for the person supervising an apprentice, but it is clear that the OP means someone with authority over them, so the question answers itself.

Comment: @Rhayene yes i am

Comment: I updated the answer. Tnx for the fast clarification.

Comment: The instructor is the employee that has gone through official training that allows him to mentor the apprentices in the company where they absolve their practical training (the apprentices go to school for the theoretical stuff). I don't know the official term in english though - if there even is one.

Comment: @Rhayene: I definitely understand the concept. But usually, a **mentor** mentors, and a **trainer** trains... If teach A-SPICE or learship today at work, I am a **trainer**, but when I will teach argentine tango tomorrow afternoon, I will be an **instructor** (because tango is a mostly-physical activity, unlike engineering).

Comment: As I said - I don't know the right translation because it is more than just mentoring - the person in charge is like the boss of the apprentices and responsible for them but often not the manager that gives them work (maybe more like a team lead?) It is kind of a special position.

Answer (score 6):

> *Is running allowed?*

You mentioned : *"I just got scolded by my instructor for running."*

So, the answer is **No** (in context of the question and your organisation).

Like it or not, as long as you're an employee, you need to keep up with the etiquette and norms of the organization.

We understand you're new to the professional environment, and it's time for you to understand the differences between a college campus and a workplace. While at work, you need to *wear* your professional attire, regardless of your position in the organization. You represent the organization, so your behavior in and around the workplace also counts.

Comment: He didn't just run, he Naruto Ran, for the memes of course.
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vS1ZohQziGY

Answer (score -4):

I'm going to disagree with the other answers: this is not a question of professionalism, but of safety.

Running indoors is dangerous: you could easily run into someone, and unintentionally hurt them. If that were to happen, how would you justify this?

Running outdoors is your perogrative: if a company would pass you over for running outdoors, they aren't worth trying to climb the ladder in. If this is an educational institution, the instructor can go pound sand. They have no jurisdiction over what you do outside of the school.

Also: I would recommend completely ignoring the advice of anyone who has at all implied your personal interests are reflective of your professionalism. Again: any organization that believes that, is wrong. Full stop.

Comment: "Running outdoors" is OP's prerogative as long as "outdoors" = "outside of company premises". They can even run indoors, in those places called gyms. (and even in company premises if they have in-house gyms as employee benefits)